# atan not producing correct results.

Tags: c++, trigonometry

So I try `atan(4/3)` and print it out and i get 0.78 radians but online `atan(4/3)` is ~0.927 radians. Why am i getting conflicting results?

```
std::cout << std::atan(4 / 3)<< std::endl;
```

that's literally all i did to check and its not giving me right answer unless google is lying to me as well. It should be giving me 0.927. 
even something like atan(7/3) is giving me an answer that is off by 0.06. What's going on here is this common problem?

Comment: 4/3 == 1 (these are integers). Hence you have atan(1)

Comment: Integer division truncates any decimals.

Comment: As a simple rule of thumb, **don't use `atan`**. If you'd used `atan2`, you wouldn't have encountered this problem (and it's other advantages are even more compelling).

Comment: Next time _divide and conquer_. You should have tested without the `atan`, and you'd have found that `4/3` is not what you thought it was.